# how to setup cron job for Lumen Applicaiton in shared hosting (using CPanel)?

Tags: cron, cpanel, lumen

I have created one command which will add some record to mysql database.

When I execute command with terminal, command is adding data to database.

Then I have modified Kernel.php, added command in commands array and scheduled task as below.

```
protected $commands = [

           \App\Console\Commands\AddData::class,
   ]; 
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('word:add')->everyMinute();      
    }
```

I have setup cron job in CPanel.

Command Setting : Once per minute.

Command added as :

> /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/sitename/projectPath &&
>   php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

But it is not working - i.e. not adding row to database table neither I am getting any error from in CPanel for cron job. am I missing anything or I am doing something wrong with it?

Comment: I tried for below command but this also dont work.

`*  *  *  *  *  cd /home/hostcd1m/public_html/sitename/projectPath && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out the problem.
for this case, we need to give path of artisan file, so the command would be

`*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/sitename/projectPath/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`